# Determining $L$ from Hund's rules

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum

So I was reading through Griffiths and was doing the exercise explaining why carbon has to have the value $L=1$ which they explained as that the spin is symmetric so the orbital momentum has to be antisymmetric. I do not however see why L=0 and L=2 are symmetric whilst L=1 ( would 3 then also be antisymmetric?) is not. Furthermore if this is the case why does element boron with 5 electrons also have L=1 since it's spin is a 1/2 (antisymmetric).

If somebody could explain this to me it would be appreciated :)

The context information is in 3rd edition Griffiths introduction to quantum mechanics subsection 5.2 exercise 5.18B

Comment: What page/chapter so people can look it up for context if needed.

Comment: I edited the question to include this!